# Linking SFML static libs to project

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, sfml

Good morning! I'm moving from shared SFML libs to static. But I have a lot of errors: `g++` couldn't find some libs. I used this tutorial :https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Build-your-SFML-project-with-CMake . My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(LastFail)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs/)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs/)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_INIT g++)

add_definitions(-std=c++1y -w)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)

include_directories(
    include/
    libs/include/
)

file(GLOB SRC
    "src/*/*.cpp"
    "src/*.cpp"
)

add_executable(LastFail ${SRC})

target_link_libraries(LastFail
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libjsoncpp.a
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libsfml-audio-s.a
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libsfml-graphics-s.a
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libsfml-network-s.a
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libsfml-system-s.a
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libsfml-window-s.a
)

set_target_properties(LastFail PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME "LastFail"
    CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT 1
)
```

Small part of my errors:

> JoystickImpl.cpp:(.text+0x1166): undefined reference to 'udev_device_get_syspath'
>   libs/libsfml-window-s.a(JoystickImpl.cpp.o): In function 'sf::priv::JoystickImpl::open(unsigned int)':
>   JoystickImpl.cpp:(.text+0x19ed): undefined reference to 'udev_device_new_from_syspath'

How do I fix that? I need to do that cross-platform way. Thanks!

**Edit:**

Of course, I have a directory called `libs` with all needed libraries.

Comment: ` undefined reference to 'udev_device_get_syspath` means you are not linking the library in which that function is defined. It is `libudev`.

Comment: @MikeKinghan, thank you! But you know, there is a lot of missed libs. I need kind of cmake script for linking them all... And it **must** be cross-platform. If you want to see all errors, I had pasted them all: http://pastebin.com/erfnieXC.

Comment: `And it must be cross-platform.` - what is it mean in case, when you have **libraries shipped with your project**? Do you want to ship all libraries for **all possibles platforms** with your project? Or what? What is a question/problem actually?

Comment: I want to sheep SFML and json-cpp with my project, so every one can have it from the box. But how to do that with cmake?

Comment: I need to link all needed libs for sfml, if its linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, packaging all dependencies with the project itself is generally a bad idea, but for game-like applications there could be exceptions.

In your case, the problem is not within packaged SFML, but `libudev` library. This library is

1. Linux-specific (not cross-platform)
2. Can't be linked statically (well, it probably could, but i bet it is a very bad idea, because library you linked in could be different version that udev daemon running on the host machine)

So, you need to add `udev` to your `target_link_libraries()` anyway.

Comment: I need kind of a cmake script for linking **all** dependencies/ I'm not able to do that my self.

Comment: This "script" is basically listing all your dependencies in that `target_link_libraries()` call.

Comment: Could you help me, please? I actually don't know anything, about cmake files.

Comment: Find out names of all libraries you depend on (like `udev`) and add this line to your CMakeLists.txt: `target_link_libraries(LastFail udev other_lib1 other_lib2 ...)`